# How can I design a navigation bar where one group of items are aligned left and another group aligned right with CSS Flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The Code A is from the [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Typical_Use_Cases_of_Flexbox).

The Image A is the result of Code A.

I hope to desgin a UI just like Image B,  the two labels on the left of the bar, and the two labels on the right of the bar.

But Code B can't get the result, how can I do?

**Code A**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3 is longer</a></li>
    <li class="push-right"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.push-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

**Code B**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="push-right"><a href="#">Page 3 is longer</a></li>
    <li class="push-right"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

//The same
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

**Added Content**

Thanks! Maybe the Code C is good way.

**Code C**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>

    <li class="push-right"><a href="#">Page 3 is longer</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.push-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the "push-right" class on the third item, not the fourth. It then pushes both to the right.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.push-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Page 1</a>
  <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  <a class="push-right" href="#">Page 3 is longer</a>
  <a href="#">Page 4</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

nav > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3 is longer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question? Maybe the Code C is a good way.

Comment: Sorry that's not valid markup.  Per the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element): "The items of the list are the li element child nodes of the ul element."